# Что означает выражение "отмечен печатью рока"?

Tags: выражения

Увидела это выражение в книге Эми Чуа, и все никак не могу найти значение в интернете. Знаю, что книга была переведена с аннлийского. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А что непонятного? "Рок" здесь в значении "злая судьба".

Comment: А выражение "его преследовал злой рок" понимаете? У Есенина есть строчка: "Дар поэта — ласкать и карябать, роковая на нем печать"

Comment: в интернете даже в поиске по новостям "печать рока" выдаётся десятки матчей. Какая часть именно непонятна - что такое "печать рока" или как можно быть отмеченным печатью?

Comment: Значит, человек обречен , его с рождения преследуют несчастья.

Comment: Отмечен печатью судьбы. Предопределение. Попробуйте подумать над контекстом этой элементарной метафоры. Почитайте о фатализме, удаче, Терри Пратчетта "Цвет волшебства" (там этот Рок присутствует лично), проклятиях, предопределениях, роковых женщинах - femme fatale... и т.п. Смотря что конкретно имелось в виду именно - в контексте (неплохо бы добавить его в вопрос). Рок вообще-то чаще негативное.
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/рок
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Судьба

Comment: shabunc, https://youtu.be/LUmHo85M78Y?t=276 :))

Answer (score 1):

`Печать судьбы` или `печать рока` на ком-то означает, что этот человек мистически обречён на какую-то трагическую судьбу.   Например:

> Я сирота в этом мире. Ни друзей, ни родных. Всегда один. От самого
> рождения **печать рока** на мне. Обреченный, отверженный… Ну, что ж?
> Видно, быть так.
> (Д. С. Мережковский. *Александр Первый*, 1922)